# reputation change in the tooltip aggregate values

Tags: support, reputation

On Stack Overflow, I've recently (on the 20th of Aug) gained 10 reputation for an upvote on one of my answers.

If I check the reputation tab in my profile, it states "+10 upvote"

However, if I hover my mouse over my name in the top of the window, the tooltip shows +20 for that answer.

On the 7th of August I had +10 for that answer too, so it looks like you're **aggregating** all the scores for that answer for the current month.

Is this by design, or **should scores not be aggregated in the tooltip**?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any screenshots to clarify what tooltips you are referring to?

Comment: Hope the image clarifies it. if it's too big, please tell me so as i will resize it

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is by design. If you view your reputation tab, you will see actions grouped by post (altough first by day), so grouping them together here seems to be following that idea.

I suppose it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), but can't 100% confirm.

Comment: Although i can't confirm either it's quite possible to be by design. If anyone would be kind enough to confirm it i'd be glad to accept this answer